# How to make the loop run again if boolean is false

Tags: java, loops, methods

My issue is the when boolean is false it still returns i and places it in the array lotto.  How do I fix it so that when boolean is false it will drop i and run a another random number for that element.

```
package LottoNumbers;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LottoNumbers {
//check for duplicates in each array

    public static boolean isFound(int[] lotto, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++) {
            if (lotto[i] == number ) {
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
          //DO SOMETHING IF FALSE THAT WILL GET RID OF THE NUMBER

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //specify length of array
        int[] lotto = new int[6];
        //determine how many arrays
        for (int Set = 1; Set <= 5; Set++) {
            //assign random numbers to each array element
            for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++) {
                int number= 0;
                isFound(lotto, number = (int) (Math.random() * 50));
                lotto[i] = number;

            }
              Arrays.sort(lotto);


            //sort elements in array 
            //Sort arrays to specified Set numbers
            if (Set == 1) {
                System.out.printf("LOTTO Numbers for set 1 --> ");

            } else if (Set == 2) {
                System.out.print("LOTTO Numbers for set 2 --> ");

            } else if (Set == 3) {
                System.out.print("LOTTO Numbers for set 3 --> ");

            } else if (Set == 4) {
                System.out.print("LOTTO Numbers for set 4 --> ");

            } else if (Set == 5) {
                System.out.print("LOTTO Numbers for set 5 --> ");

            }

            System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(lotto).replace("[", "").replace(",", "").replace("]", "") + "\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking to only fill lotto[] when boolean returns true.

Comment: Does the solution below help you?

Comment: I can not use an array list for this assignment.  However inneficient my for loops were, that is a requirement.  :/

Comment: That's okay - I included a solution using the array and the for loop as well.

Comment: I am trying to figure out that solution.

Comment: I assume that I need to place bool wasFound in my first method.  But I am not 100% sure where.

Comment: The for loop I put in there replaces the for loop you have inside the for (int Set = 1; Set <= 5; Set++) loop.

Comment: That code returns 5 arrays of 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: I figured it out, I switched the true and false in my upper method.

Comment: Great! If what I showed you was helpful, please select the answer with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - you don't actually do anything at all with the boolean value returned by isFound. But, if you're asking whether you can only assign lotto[i] if isFound evaluates to true, one way you could do that is to change the for loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++) {
    int number;
    Boolean wasFound = isFound(lotto, number = (int) (Math.random() * 50));

    if (!wasFound)
    {
        lotto[i] = number;
    }
    else
    {
        // perform the previous iteration again
        i--;
    }
}
```

Your design is not terrifically efficient or well-designed - you're counting on a random number you generate not having been seen before, which gets significantly worse performance-wise the more numbers you've already created. A better way you could do this would be to just take a single element of a pre-existing collection of non-repeating integers in the range you want:

```
// define numbersArrayList as { 1, 2, 3, 4, ... n }
ArrayList<int> yourLottoNumbers = new ArrayList<int>()
for (int i = 0; i < yourLimit; i++)
{
    int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * numbersArrayList.length()) - 1;
    int newNumber = numbersArrayList[randomIndex];
    yourLottoNumbers.add(newNumber);
    yourLottoNumbers.remove(randomIndex);
}
```

This code executes in an amount of time directly proportional to the number of elements you need to get, rather than in a totally random amount of time, and you don't need to fudge around with repeating for loops.

Comment: int newNumber = numbersArrayList[randomIndex]; might give arrayIndexOutOfBound exception.

Comment: That should fix it now.

Comment: in fact you should mod it with numbersArrayList size, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your function to loop if it's false, because then the function would never end.

```
public static boolean IsFound(int number)
{
    //You don't need to pass the array, because it's a class level variable
    for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++)
    {
        if (lotto[i] == number)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you can simply do something like this to add to your array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = (Math.random() * 50);
    while(IsFound(randomNumber))
    {
        randomNumber = (Math.random() * 50);
    }
    lotto[i] = randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the problem as well.  I just needed to switch my boolean true and false in the upper method.  I also took the previous posters advice on my code which was the other part of the problem.